# SL5 + Prism 4.1 Dynamic XAP download takes too much time to load

Tags: silverlight, prism, mef

I am using SL5, Telerik SL5 DLLs, Prism4.1 & MEF for my application and I have splitted my main application into smaller modules. And also, i  have enabled "Reduce XAP size by enabling in application library caching" that reduced size of my main xap file from 1.5MB to 700 KB (and also, module1.xap & module2.xap files sizes are reduced to 91 KB  & 145 KB).

Problem: When i try to browse through my application over internet, my main xap file gets downloaded immediately (it shows 100% loaded with in 5 - 10 seconds) but the problem is, it is taking little more time (sometimes, it takes more time than main.xap loading took) to load and display first screen from module1.xap. I am unable to figure out the root cause of the issue. Can somebody assist me in resolving this issue?

FYI, Refer below for my clienbin contents:

[image]

Main.xap file contents:

[image]

Module1.xap file contents:

[image]

Module2.xzp file contents:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or the Developer Tools of your favorite browser to see what and when your application loads modules and external parts.

I think you get the delay cause the Telerik zips (External Parts) are loaded when you navigate to the first screen of module 1.

To reduce the load time you could rezip all .zip files with a better compression tool. I´m using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) with `Ultra` compression to reduce the size of the zip files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try your suggestions and let you know my observations.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load modules by order, you should depend modules one to another. 
You can do this in modulecatalog.xaml like this

```
<Modularity:ModuleInfo Ref="Main.xap" ModuleName="Main" ModuleType="Project.Main, Module, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" >
        <Modularity:ModuleInfo.DependsOn>
            <sys:String>Module1</sys:String>
        </Modularity:ModuleInfo.DependsOn>
```